# Getting values from two-segment list in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, list

i have a two-segment list;

```js
var list =ee.List([
  [101,12155],
  [102,12157],
  [103,12158]])
```

I can print this list with:

```js
print(list)
```

And get values for row (0) like this command:

```js
print(list.get(0))
```

But, how can i get the second values of first rows from this list?

Comment: Hi @Mehmet and welcom on GIS.StackExchange. when you add code in your question, use the mkd code hilighting system. It's also available in the question text editor. I've edit your question accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, we have two options:

1- Go with the *ee.List*

```
var list =ee.List([[101,12155], [102,12157], [103,12158]])
print(ee.List(list.get(0)).get(0))
//[101]
print(ee.List(list.get(0)).get(1))
//[12155]
print(ee.List(list.get(1)).get(0))
//[102]
```

2- Or go with *ee.Array*

```
var list =ee.Array([[101,12155], [102,12157], [103,12158]])

print(list.get([0,0]))
//[101]
print(list.get([0,1]))
//[12155]
print(list.get([1,0]))
//[102]
```

Hope it helps.